# VXML - How to assign String having ' using expr in <var> tag

Tags: xml, ivr, vxml

I am getting error when executing below statement in Vxml.
Error is due to ' in the word S'il

The String getting assigned is in French language which makes use of ' at many places. How do I fix this error?

I have tried using escape sequence for ' but that doesn't seem to be working.

> & #39; and & apos;
>   (in actual code there is no space between & and # / a)

Code is executed by Plum Voice's VXML browser. Exact error is 
        "missing ; before statement line 1
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement line 1"

```
<var name="Verbiage3" expr="' S'il vous plait veuillez saisir les 16 numeros digitaux de votre carte suivis de diese  '"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes to delimit your JavaScript string (so you must use the XML entity `&quot;` since it is in an XML attribute):

```
<var name="Verbiage3" expr="&quot;S'il vous plait veuillez saisir les 16 numeros digitaux de votre carte suivis de diese&quot;"/>
```

Or alternatively, use single quotes for the XML attribute and espace the quote in the value:

```
<var name="Verbiage3" expr='"S&apos;il vous plait veuillez saisir les 16 numeros digitaux de votre carte suivis de diese"'/>
```